# Android Use MediaRecorder to capture audio.

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I need to capture audio from microphone and after user stop talking application need to identify that user stopped talking. I have a Android 2.2 Froyo device and it has this kind of app. Since most of the apps written in Java, I was wondering how to do this. I searched everywhere, [MediaRecorder Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) but I couldn't find anything on that.

I'm using [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) tutorial and since this is general question I'm not going to post any coding.

I'm not using ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent, instead I use google speech-api, I record amr file and upload it to google speech api, and it provides me json with speech to text.

Problem is how I determine user stopped speaking.

Answer (score 1):

MediaRecorder cannot be used for that, but look into:

- [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html), which lets you capture raw audio which you can then analyze for pauses; or
- [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) (since API level 8), which lets you call a speech recognizer which already implements the endpointer detection.